# How to use regex to find the middle of a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get certain results out of the response from Blogger. I wanna get my blog names. How would I go about something like that with Regex? I've tried Googling my issue but none of the answers helped me in my case unfortunately.

So my response looks something like this:

```
\\x22http://emyblog.blogspot.com/
```

So it's always starting with the `\\x22http://` and ending with `.blogspot.com/`

I've tried the following re:

```
regEx = re.findall(b"""\x22http://(.*)\.blogspot\.com""", r)
```

But unfortunately it returned an empty list. Any idea's on how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Removing the `b` that indicates a bytestring (and thus generated a traceback, rather than an empty list), your expression worked fine for me, producing `['emyblog']`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 If I remove the **b** I get the following error **TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object** I think the **b** is required in Py3.5

Comment: Your `r` is a bytes-like object, then. Making both the expression and the string bytes objects works fine for me as well.

Comment: @Naomi: I have edited your question, could you confirm that your subject string appears correctly?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, my reponse looks like this [https://puu.sh/oY7OZ/ea5d746c28.png]

Answer (score 5):

Use a raw string, otherwise `\\x22` is interpreted as the character `"` instead of a literal string. Not sure that the `re.findall` method is the good method, `re.search` should suffice.

Assuming your byte-string is:

```
>>> r = rb'\\x22http://emyblog.blogspot.com/'
```

With byte-strings:

```
>>> res = re.search(rb'\\x22http://(.*)\.blogspot\.com/', r)
>>> res.group(1)
b'emyblog'
```

With normal strings:

```
>>> res = re.search(r'\\\\x22http://(.*)\.blogspot\.com/', r.decode('utf-8'))
>>> res.group(1)
'emyblog'
```

Comment: Hey, if I use **re.searchfindall** I get a key error **AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'searchfindall'**

Comment: Did you try it without a raw string? It works fine. This doesn't actually fix any problem, because there is no problem.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: The problem is that the original string is (can be) defined like this: `r=rb'\x22http://domain.blogspot.com'`. `\x22` isn't a double quote but a backslash, an x, a 2 and a 2.

Comment: Oh, if the original string sample is raw; yeah.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3:yes you get it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Still doesn't work it's returning None now, I'm starting to think I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

use `r''` (string is taken as *raw string literal*) instead of `b''`

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\x22http://(.*)\.blogspot\.com')
match = pattern.match('\x22http://emyblog.blogspot.com/')
match.group(1)
# 'emyblog'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working!

```
    import re
    text = "\x22http://emyblog.blogspot.com/"
    regex = re.compile('\x22http://(.*)\.blogspot\.com')
    print regex.findall(text)
```